# Spring 4.2.3.RELEASE and Hibernate 5.0.4.Final compatibility issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

Has anyone configured Spring 4.2.3.RELEASE and Hibernate 5.0.4.Final together ? Official documents from Spring say from version 4.2 spring starts supporting Hibernate version 5. But in case of configuring them together i always get the following Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AutoProxyUtils.determineTargetClass(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
at org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(EventListenerMethodProcessor.java:78)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:792)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at me.shafin.sustord.dao.App.main(App.java:8)
```

**Here is the pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework.samples.service.service</groupId>
<artifactId>RokomiMoc</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>


<properties>

    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Web -->
    <jsp.version>2.3.1</jsp.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>


    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring-security.version>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <hibernate-framework.version>5.0.4.Final</hibernate-framework.version>

    <!-- Validator -->
    <hibernate.validator.version>5.0.1.Final</hibernate.validator.version>
    <javax.validation.version>1.1.0.Final</javax.validation.version>

    <!-- File upload -->
    <commons-fileupload.version>1.3.1</commons-fileupload.version>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    <!-- Test -->
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- View -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- jsr303 validation dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.validation.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.37</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Fileupload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-fileupload.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Rest support -->
    <!-- For Spring 4.1.x and above, jackson-databind 2.3 or above is recommended, 
        in order to avoid conversion issues. -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Others -->






    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Test Artifacts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>





    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This **pom.xml** and my other configurations are quite okay with **Spring 4.0.6** and **Hibernate 4.3.6** ... Can anyone please share his/her experience with these latest version compatibility issues. Or is there anything new way to configure them together that I am missing ?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and not a snippet. Looking at the thing now it looks like you have a version conflict in your spring version, maybe a dependency pulled in by Spring Security that is overriding the spring one.

Comment: Could you please post the output of `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: @M.Deinum i have updated the error stack

Comment: As request please add the output of  `mvn:dependency:tree`.

Comment: Read up on https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Answer (score 6):

I was dealing with same problem for a few hours. I have noticed that :

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
```

This shows that lastest spring-security-core version 4.0.3.RELEASE is dependent with Spring Framework 4.2.2.RELEASE.

You have two solution for this:

1) Exclude spring-aop 4.2.2 for spring-security-core and explicitly add your dependency description for spring-aop:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE to your pom file.

2) Change your 4.2.3.RELEASE dependency to 4.2.2.RELEASE and change Hibernate version 5.0.4.Final to 5.0.2.Final

I choose second way and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `pom.xml` of `spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE`, the version of the hibernate that it is using is `5.0.3.Final`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

It is an optional dependency, so it will not be resolved as a transitive dependency. You still need to provide the necessary hibernate jars like what you are currently doing. You only need to modify the version to the official version that it is using.

```
<hibernate-framework.version>5.0.3.Final</hibernate-framework.version>
```

Comment: i tried  hibernate version 5.0.3  and others of version 5.. but no help

Comment: I am usign Apache tomcat 8.0.27